# My Haskell code isn't compiling because of an import error

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to run my code in my command line to double-check my work. My code works with iHaskell but not with ghci.

I'm getting this error:

```
test.hs:6:1: error: parse error on input ‘import’
  |
6 | import Data.Char
```

Here is my code:

```
main :: IO()
import Data.Char

...

result = f "hElLo"
main = print result
```

Any idea why this is not working? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Imports need to be at the beginning of the file, before any function definitions. Move the import before `main :: IO()` and it should work.

Comment: (Also, note that it’s generally considered good style to put type signatures next to the functions they’re associated with: here, I’d personally put the type signature `main :: IO ()` on the line immediately before the corresponding definition `main = print result`.)

Comment: Yes, my question is answered. I can't accept my answer yet, so I'll mark it as accepted in a couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @bradrn for the advice.

I moved the import above the main so now it's:

```
import Data.Char

...

result = f "hElLo"
main :: IO()
main = print result
```